# Drupal 7 One admin, multisite, multiuser, same structure what is best configuration?

Tags: drupal-7, sql-update

I am developing a web site with drupal that has lot of instances. My case is

- Every site same structure but different content. Websites made by drupal multisite conf. Same codebase, different database.
- Only me user 1 every sites. Client is owner of the site, only add and view contents of their website.
- The problem is I will keep developing web site and change structure and configurations. For example new or updated content types, new fields, new or updated views, rules etc. When I updated 1 sample web site, what is the best approach update all current websites?

Is it possible managing views, contetnt types, field, rules, enabled modules on one site. By the time maybe over 1000 website will added to system. and it is hard to update 1 by 1 features modules. (Also features modules doesnt carry some confs.)

Comment: You could check Domain Access module (https://drupal.org/project/domain), for an alternative approach to a multisite Drupal installation.

Comment: Thanks pamatt. Domain Access module great aproach in my case.

Comment: On domain access module is it possible to not share user? each domain editor must crete their own users and others may cant see the users.